# Trying to compute: $\lim_{x\to a} (\sqrt{x-a}-\sqrt{x})$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{x-a}-\sqrt{x}$$

This looks like a mundane (one sided) limit, it seems we need only to make:

$$ \sqrt{a-a}-\sqrt{a}=-\sqrt{a}  $$

With $a>0$. But in the answers from the book I took this limit from, the answer is $0$. This is a bit shocking for me because if this limit actually yields $0$, I have no idea about what should be done to compute it. The result of this limit being $-\sqrt{a}$ also agrees with some computations I've done with Mathematica (numerically and via Taylor series).  Am I wrong in something or the book has a typo?

Comment: No, I would agree with you.

Comment: Definitely seems like a typo in your book.

Comment: It's not shocking to see typos in a maths book....

Comment: The typo would be this: the intended limit with answer zero is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x-a}-\sqrt{a})=0$$

Comment: The answer is most definitely what you say. Sounds like a typo on your book's end.